# Last cell selection .End(xlup) using VBA in Excel 2003 'lists' - requires two .Select to get correct cell?

Tags: excel, vba, list

I'm a new convert from Experts-Exchange since I noticed they increased the 'Free Premium Services' points threshold.

It seems that Excel 2003 has issues with the End(xlup) command when using it in a worksheet that contains an Excel 'List'.. If I select a cell **outside the 'list' boundary**, and then try to select the last cell in the worksheet by using VBA, I have to call the .Select function twice to make sure I am getting the correct cell.  If the original cell is **inside the 'list' boundary** then i only need one .Select.  My hacked together solution is below, with two selects, as I can never be sure what cell may be selected on save.  I include a version check at open to run different code in Excel 2007 (this code fails in 2007, where the .End(xlUp) command works properly).

Is there a more eloquent way to handle this? 
Thanks for any help!

```
.Range("A1").Select
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Select
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Select
'two .Selects needed to select correct cell in Excel 2003 list because original selection (A1) was not in list'

.Range("A1").Select
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp)(-2, 1).Select
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp)(-2, 1).Select
'two .Selects needed to select correct cell in Excel 2003 list because original selection (A1) was not in list'

.Cells(.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp)(-3, 1).Select
'only one select needed here because original selection above was within the list'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my use of .End(xlUp).Select prior to acting on the .End(xlUp) cell was causing the problem.  If I simply avoid the .End(xlUp).Select prior to operating on the .End(xlUp) cell, the problem is less complex.  It can be easily solved by preceding any .End(xlUp) operation with .Range("A1").Select.  See the code for explanation.  This doesn't really fix the problem with improper .End(xlUp) cell 'selection' - but I'm not interested in 'selecting' the cells, just operating on them.  I must mention that I use .Range("A1").Select because A1 is outside of the 'list' that I'm manipulating via VBA.

```
'commented out - just need to add a ".Range("A1").Select" prior to any .End(xlUp) usage (besides .End(xlUp).Select) to make it work in Excel 03
'.Range("A1").Select
'.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(0, 1).Select
'.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(0, 1).Select
''two .Selects needed to select correct cell in Excel 2003 'Lists'
'Set EntryDate = Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(0, 1) 'no need to select cell first, then operate on it, as in the code above

'fixed code below
.Range("A1").Select 'needed for Excel 03 to select correct cell
Set EntryDate = Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp) 'just operate on the cell instead of selecting it first
```

Answer (score 1):

See how this does:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim rngLstCell As Excel.Range
    Set rngLstCell = GetLastCell(Excel.Worksheets("Sheet1"))
    MsgBox "The last cell is: " & rngLstCell.Address, vbInformation
End Sub

Public Function GetLastCell(ByVal ws As Excel.Worksheet) As Excel.Range
    Dim rngRtnVal As Excel.Range
    With ws.UsedRange
        Set rngRtnVal = .Find("*", .Cells(1, 1), , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If rngRtnVal Is Nothing Then
            Set rngRtnVal = .Cells(1, 1)
        End If
    End With
    Set GetLastCell = rngRtnVal
End Function
```

Using find may seem weird at first but it ends up being the most reliable way due to some vagaries in the way empty cells are handled.

This may not be perfect if your data is non-normalized (jagged).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the ranges that you were working with were identical? You shouldn't get different results using the End property in Excel 2007 versus 2003.

Looking at your code:

```
.Range("A1").Select
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Select
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Select
```

Each of these lines of code have exactly zero impact on one another. No honest explanation can be offered about why the End property is giving you different results based on the code you've provided. From what's written, you should get the same results each time. (That's assuming you're working with identical ranges.) I'd be suspicious of any other code that's being executed. I can offer a couple general tips though: If you use End starting with a blank cell, it will stop at the first non-blank cell. If you start with a non-blank cell, the opposite is true. Looking at the screenshot below:

```
Range("B13").End(xlUp).Select 'selects B12
Range("B12").End(xlUp).Select 'selects B2
Range("A12").End(xlUp).Select 'selects A6
```

[image]

So whether or not your list is contiguous is an issue. Also, it is not necessary to select a range before you do something to it. Telling Excel to select cell A1 does not impact how it executes `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Select`. Assuming that line is within a With block that refers to a worksheet, that line of code is the same thing as navigating to cell A65536 (or A1048576 in Excel 2007) and pressing Ctrl + Up. Assuming that cell is blank, Excel will navigate upwards until it finds the first non-blank cell in column A. If your With block refers to a range object, then that line of code will go to the first column, bottom row of that range and navigate upwards until it comes to the first blank or non-blank cell.

Comment: Hey Nick,
Thanks for your detailed post...but both Excel versions work as expected with regular worksheets.  The behavior changes when working with Excel's 'List' functionality (Data>List in 03, .  Looks like it is implemented quite differently in 03 vs 07.  
  
see http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/Excel2007Tables.asp

Comment: I just created a table in Excel 2010 and was able to duplicate the behavior I described above, both with the End property as well as with the keyboard shortcuts directly in the sheet.

Comment: A thought: are you possibly using End on a filtered list? That might effect your results. Other than that, I'm outta ideas. :)

Comment: It's 03 that has the problematic behavior, Excel 07 works as expected.  I originally created the list in Excel 07, and everything worked perfectly, until I opened it up in 03, and the end function was always a row off.  More specifically, the cell selected through the use of the End(xlUp).Select function varied, based on whether the previously selected cell was inside the 'list' or not.   Thanks again for your help.  I'll give your post a loser look and

Comment: e.g.: List is A3:D10.  I select cell A1 (outside of the list) and then run the End(xlUp).Select function, the selected cell is one row below where it should be.  If I select B4 and then run the End(xlUp).Select function, the proper cell is selected.  This is quite frustrating as you can imagine.  So my fix was to programmatically ensure that a cell within the list would be selected prior to the 'real' select function.  So I select A1 (outside of list) and then run an .End(xlUp).Select function to select a cell in the list (i could have just as easily selected A3), and then .End(xlUp).Select

Comment: I have found that other operations on cells using the .End(xlUp) (besides.Select) function work just fine without a preceding in-list 'select'.  The simple action of 'Selecting' a cell in the list changes the list size (in Excel 03).  A 'New' blank row is added to the bottom of the list, thus confusing the .End(xlUp) function.  However, as long as the originally selected cell is outside of the list, then .End(xlUp) actions (besides .Select) work just fine.  Thus my final fix is below: precede any .End(xlUp) operation with a .Select outside of the list.  It's a hack but it works

Comment: What are you calling .End(xlUp) against? When you post code here, you should fully qualify your statements: Range("A1").End(xlUp) will have a different result than, say, Range("Z56").End(xlUp).

Comment: See my original post.
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Select

Comment: You cannot begin a line of code with a dot, unless it is contained in a With block. By itself, that line of code is not valid and I do not see a With statement anywhere in your code samples.